# Customising Google Marker

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I followed google's tutorial on setting marker and here is something strange I have found.

Following exactly what they do is fine, but when I tried to use data from my database instead of the hardcoded string of text for content of the marker, it doesn't work any more.

Here is the original code:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    title:"Hello World!"
});
```

Here is what I have and not working:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    title: <%= @person.name %>
});
```

Comment: What does the generated JS look like where you're setting the title property?  Are you getting a JS error?  Maybe you need to wrap it in quotes: `title: '<%= @person.name %>'`

Comment: Cool, I've posted this as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to wrap the title attribute in single or double quotes:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    title: '<%= @person.name %>'
});
```

Otherwise the generated JS you're getting client side might look like:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    title: Joe Bloggs
});
```

Which wouldn't be valid!